# How to adjust Java AWT/Swing UI to system settings?

Tags: java, swing, awt, kde-plasma

Linux desktop environments (KDE, Gnome) support dark theme which might inverse typical colors.

```
MyPanel extends JPanel {
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       //without changing color default font color should be used?
       g.drawString("my string", 10, 10);
   }
}
```

Can I get in Java system preferences for text colors, UI background, so that code above won't paint white text on light gray background? At least in KDE with Krita dark theme Java's panel uses gray instead of using system colors.

Basically when creating new `JPanel` I'd like to call something like

```
setBackground("default system color for panel background");
```

Comment: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`?

Comment: This doesn't change text colors in KDE, nor panel's background.

Comment: You could use the `UIManager` class to get information such as the fonts, colors, etc. used by the current look and feel. See [this example that shows the various keys](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-uimanager-color-keys-list).

Comment: [System Colors for Linux KDE user interface themes](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2010/11/java_tip_systemcolors_linux_kde_user_interface_themes#AccessingKDEthemecolorsfromJava).  TLDR: There's no easy way in Java to get the KDE colors.

Answer (score 1):

Try `UIManager Class`

```
Color color = UIManager.getColor ( "Panel.background" );
g.setColor(color);
```

Here is list [UIManager color key values](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-uimanager-color-keys-list)